# How to define a related resource URI in JSON:API

Tags: api, rest, relationship, json-api

In the json:api format relationships are defined with a type and a id. 
Like in the example bellow. The article has a relationship with the type people and the id 9.

Now if i want to fetch the related resource i use the URI from "links.related"

```
// ...
{
  "type": "articles",
  "id": "1",
  "attributes": {
    "title": "Rails is Omakase"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "author": {
      "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
        "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
      },
      "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
    }
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
  }
}
// ...
```

But in my case the related resource (people) are in a separate API. There is no way to get the full people data from the articles API nor is it possible to include it. The only way to get the related data would be a call to:

```
http://example.com/v1-2/people/9/
```

Where can i define the relation between the URI and people:9

Or in other words: How would a client know where to fetch the related resource?